# Stuck with deriving tangent line at a point

Tags: limits

I have been asked to find the tangent to the given curve at the point indicated.

This is what I know:

We find the slope $m$ at the specific point on the graph by $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$
we also know that $$\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} = m,$$ and therefore $$y_1=m(x_1-x_0)+y_0.$$

Now, I have $$y=\sqrt{x+1}\text{ at }x=3$$
so I have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{h}.$$
I expanded:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h+1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{h} =\\
\frac{\sqrt{x+h+1}-2}{h}=\\
\frac{\sqrt{x+h+1}-2}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h+1}+2}{\sqrt{x+h+1}+2}=\\
\frac{x+h+1-4}{h(\sqrt{x+h+1}+2)}$$

From the point where I am stuck I have tried all sort of different ways to get the final answer but I do not understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is false:

$$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \neq a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$$

---

However, your result is still good, as you did not use the equality you wrote, so you correctly derived

$$\frac{x+h+1-4}{h(\sqrt{x+h+1} + 2)}.$$

But why did you only replace $x$ with $3$ in one, not all expressions? Simply replace $x$ with $3$ and see what you get.

Comment: Corrected the error.Still replacing x within the 1/(sqrt[h]+4). Which is the same result as I get with all the other ways of deriving it? But I do not see why this is wrong.

Comment: @ALEXANDER I edited your answer to mathjax notation. Now, what did you get when you replaced $x$ with $3$ in the expression $$\frac{x+h+1-4}{h(\sqrt{x+h+1} + 2)}?$$

Comment: h/h(2+Sqrt(4+h)

Comment: And, have you canceled out $h$? Also, try to use mathjax notation. For example, you can write a nicer fraction if you put your expression into dollar signs and use `$\frac{num}{den}$` to get $\frac{num}{den}$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to convert Latex or MathMl to mathjax

Comment: Just write Latex, MathJax *is* latex.

Comment: $\frac{h}{h\left(\sqrt{h+4}+2\right)}$, giving me $\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}+4}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Well done. Not that hard, really. You did most of the work yourself.

Comment: No! It so easy that the fact that I dont see it straight away is embarrassing. But just have be be more clear on all the rules and keep practicing! Thanks for showing me that by using $ signs around the latex code one get it in the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

To get the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ at $x=3$, we differentiate the expression and sub in 3.
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\implies f'(3)=\frac{1}{4}$$
So we know that the tangent line is $$y=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{5}{4}$$
Alternatively, we can use the more tedious method of evaluating limits.
$$m=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{h+4} -2}{h}\frac{\sqrt{h+4}+2}{\sqrt{h+4}+2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{h+4}+2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
to get the same answer.